# Как реализовать модификацию модуля Laravel, без потери расширяемости?

Tags: php, laravel

Существуют определенные приватные пакеты для Laravel, загружаю через композер, дальше ServiceProvider`ом все подключается.

Каким образом изменить(модифицировать) какую либо из функций пакета, (не в папке vendor естественно), чтобы не потерять расширяемость пакета, то есть если выйдет обновление, можно было безболезненно обновить его у проекте. Все роут обращается к vendor/*path_to_package*/ изменить.
Делать vendor_publish модуля и обращать роут к опубликованному пакету - не подойдет по ряду причин, главная из них, теряется принцип расширяемости, ибо при публикации "сотрутся" все модификации, а если не публиковать, то смысл обновлять его.

Может кто подскажет литературу или т.п. касаемо вопроса. Спасибо.

Comment: Если пакет не предоставляет возможности наследования своих функциональных классов, которые вы собираетесь дорабатывать, то только клонированием проекта и использованием патчей. Опять же это зависит от конкретного пакета - у одних вы сможете расширить функционал через наследование, и других - через контракты, у третьих - через инъекцию (DI) нужного вам класса.